# Where to find an overview of backed Collection methods/classes

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to find an overview of all methods in the `java.util` package returning backed Collections (and Maps). The only ones easy to find are the `synchronizedXX` and `immutableXX`. But there are others like `subMap()`. Is there a more comfortable way to find out more about all `util` methods returning backed collections than to actually read the docs? A visual overview maybe?

the tutorial for wrapped classes (has been proposed twice as an answer) at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/wrapper.html is oblivious of the NavigableSet/Map interfaces and therefore does not provide an overview of methods returning backed Collections

Comment: The other methods i could find can be found in the NavigableSet/Map interfaces and are headSet/Map, tailSet/Map and subSet/Map. The API docs do not explicitly mention the backing, but phrase it like "..returns a view of the portion..."

Comment: I know of no such overview -- if you need it, you'll probably have to create it. :-)

Comment: @Kevin Bourillon im afraid youre right (sigh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this doesn't exactly answer your question (and I risk being down-voted), but I will try anyway.

You should try to study the collections API as much as you can, in general it is good advice for any programming language/platform to invest some time, and learn the basics.

When studying Java collections you will also notice some oddities in the design, and will also realize that there are many things that are not provided that you either have to build your own or get them from somewhere else (such as Apache commons).

In any case, using a modern IDE (such as IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse) will make things a lot easier on you. Both have ways of searching for symbols with a few keystrokes and also let you navigate the collections API (and any source code you throw at them) making it a lot easier to figure out what is available and how you might take advantage of it.

Comment: I agree.  The best reference is the source code, and a good Java IDE lets you jump right to the API's implementation source code quickly and easily (F3 in Eclipse, Ctrl+B in NetBeans/IntelliJ.)  Also useful is Eclipse's Ctrl+Shift+T "Open any type in the classpath."  And even if there is a "master list", it would probably fall out of date -- even Oracle's own docs leave a few things out. Learn to quickly and efficiently read and navigate the Java API source code, and you will never be left wanting for information again. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try [this mnemonic](http://antonshchastnyi.blogspot.com/2011/11/tiny-java-mnemonic-backed-collections.html) to understand some methods from `TreeSet` and `TreeMap`.

It's a bit tricky though there's a numeric `TreeSet` (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) below. So it's easy to remember that `headSet()` & `headMap()` methods work with the "Head" of the collection.

Also the mnemonic describes that there are two cases of using `headSet` with different results:

- `headSet(element)`
- `headSet(element, inclusive)`.

Comment: Thanks Anton. Nice idea with the illustration on the inclusiveness.

Answer (score 0):

The [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/wrapper.html) has a page on wrapper classes.

Comment: the tutorial is oblivious of the NavigableSet/Map interfaces and therefor does not provide an overview of methods returning backed Collections